# Problems with file ownership in a linux group

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have an ubuntu ec2 server.

I have a user, `ubuntu` created by aws for which I have the ssh key.
I have a team of 4 developers who have their own users and separate keys. Lets call them `dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4`.

Now I created a group called `devs` in which I added all 4 developer users. dev1 - dev4.

Problem I am facing is when `dev1` upload/create a file via ftp on server machine, `dev2` is not able to edit the file or upload another version of same file created by dev1, even though they are in same group, because its ownership lies with `dev1`.

How can I solve this problem. I want everyone in my group `devs` to be able to modify add or create files, in my /var/www/html/ folder, regardless of who created that file.

Can I give group ownership in linux be default? As far as I know ownership can always be with users not the group. Is there a simple and straightforward solution to this?

group structure -
[image]

You can see 4 users in group devs

Comment: Check out the `umask` manpage. Setting umask to `0002` for the users might help to ensure that newly created files have `rw-rw-r--` access mode.

Comment: Could you show the output of these commands? "groups dev1", "groups dev2", "groups dev3" and "groups dev4". And, in /var/www/, the output of (in order to see the permission of the interested folder): "ls -l"

Comment: @DurdenP: There is just one group "devs", dev1, dev2... are the users in group dev. I have attached image in original question. If i run your command, "groups dev1" - output - dev1 : dev1 <groupname>

Comment: The groups command shows the group memberships of an USER. So, if you execute "groups devs" you will see the group memberships of the user "devs": https://linux.die.net/man/1/groups

Answer (score 1):

The steps that you have to follow are:

- Create the group:

`sudo groupadd devs`

- Create the users:

`sudo useradd dev1`

`sudo useradd dev2`

`sudo useradd dev3`

`sudo useradd dev4`

- Set a password for the users:

`sudo passwd dev1`

`sudo passwd dev2`

`sudo passwd dev3`

`sudo passwd dev4`

- Insert the users in the "devs" group:

`sudo usermod -a -G devs dev1`

`sudo usermod -a -G devs dev2`

`sudo usermod -a -G devs dev3`

`sudo usermod -a -G devs dev4`

- Check that the interested folder (/var/www/html) has the right permissions. 
  For example, I created 2 users (dev1 and dev2) for a test and inserted them in the group "devs". I created a file with the user "dev2". 
  These are the permissions:

> rw-rw-r-- 1 dev2    devs       10 Sep  6 20:46 test.txt

The owner is "dev2" but the group is "devs". The permissions in my file for the group are "rw" (read/write) so, all the members of the group can read/write. 
For more info about the linux file permissions: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions